# How to tune horizontal node position in d3 sankey.js?

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am trying to plot some flow diagrams using d3's `sankey.js`. 
I am stuck at arranging nodes x positions in the diagrams.

[image: diagram example]

`t2_a` should be in same column as `t2_b` as they represent quantity from same time period. However by default this is placed at the end which gives wrong interpretation.

I can arrange manually for small number of nodes but its really difficult when number of nodes increase. Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72570111/12779682) see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sankey.js comment the moveSinksRight call in computeNodeBreadths:

```
  function computeNodeBreadths() {
    var remainingNodes = nodes,
        nextNodes,
        x = 0;

    while (remainingNodes.length) {
      nextNodes = [];
      remainingNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node.x = x;
        node.dx = nodeWidth;
        node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
          nextNodes.push(link.target);
        });
      });
      remainingNodes = nextNodes;
      ++x;
    }

    //
    // moveSinksRight(x); <-- comment this
    scaleNodeBreadths((width - nodeWidth) / (x - 1));
  }
```

Comment: @Chakresh: Did you to try this solution?